# What is HDFS data locality?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

When we talk about data locality whatever MR or Spark. I am a little bit confused, does data locality mean read data from the local machine directly from OS (Use local file reading protocol) or just access data from local based on HDFS protocol?

Answer (score 1):

A very fundamental question that would be nice we all understand correctly.

In Spark, among the five traits of a RDD is *"Optionally, a list of preferred locations to compute each split on (e.g. block locations for an HDFS file)"* (see the [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) API scaladoc).

Whenever a `DAGScheduler` schedules execution of the tasks for a Spark job it goes over the list of preferred locations and tries to "place an order" to that compute node that a Spark executor runs on. If successful, the computation is as close to the data it needs as possible.

That gives the advantage that it is the computation to move not the data (which would be more expensive due to network bandwidth and the data size).

Comment: Got it. Maybe the question is not clear enough. My scenario is, we build spark runs in docker with --net=host mode. And the docker container runs exactly on the data node where the target file located. I want to make spark visit the data directly from the data node (if the data and the spark executor on the same server), I didn't know to implement this do we need rewrite the file reader to read the data directly from OS from hdfs data folder or just tell spark say: the data is on local machine and spark will visit hdfs automatically. BTW: the spark runs in mesos, not in yarn of hdfs.

Comment: _" I didn't know to implement this"_  it's done automatically and you don't have to implement anything for your particular use case. Do you have any reasons to think it is otherwise?